# How to find $10 + 15 + 20 + 25 + \dots + 1500$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

During a test I was given the following question:

What is $$10+15+20+25+...+1490+1495+1500=?$$

After process of elimination and guessing, $ came up with an answer.  Can anyone tell me a simple way to calculate this problem without having to try to actually add the numbers?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: Please change to title to something more descriptive.

Comment: I guess Ronnie chose to ignore... edited the title and tag.

Comment: oh im sorry i didn't see your comment

Comment: No worries. Please just keep in mind to give more descriptive titles to the questions you ask, in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Hint 1** -  Is there anything you can factor out of all the numbers?

**Hint 2** -  Do you know how to sum $1 + 2 + \cdots + n$ in a simple way?

**EDIT** - Your process in the comments is not wrong, but I don't feel like it's very intuitive.

I do think it's immediately clear that all the numbers in your sum above are divisible by 5.  That is, we can rewrite
$$10 + 15 + 20 + \cdots + 1500 = 5(2 + 3 + 4 + \cdots + 300)$$

Maybe not as obvious, but incredibly useful to know, is that
$$1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Finally notice $2 + 3 + \cdots + 300$ is *almost* $1 + 2 + \cdots + 300$, and you can use the above formula to finish the problem.

Comment: would it be 225745?

Comment: That looks right to me.  You should post your process, too, if you're interested in feedback for that.

Comment: ok well what i did was (after doing some reasearch) i used this formula n(a1+an)/2 substituded the values (299*(10+1500)/2) and got 451490/2 which gave me 225745

Comment: This isn't really what my answer was intending.  I'll edit with the process I was thinking.

Comment: ok thank you for helping me with this

Comment: hello thank you for your process.  I used your formula and for n I used 300.  so 300*301=90300.  90300/2=45150.  I then multiplied that by 5 but i got 225750.  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Ronnie:  Think about how the sum from 1 to 300 differs from the sum from 2 to 300.  (This is what Hans was implicitly asking you to think about when he said "almost".)

Answer (score 6):

HINT: 
$(10 + 1500) + (15 + 1495) + (20 + 1490) +  \cdots + (750 + 760) + 755$.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the method C. F. Gauss would have used ;)

---

**Factor out 5:**

$5(2+3+4+5+...+297+298+299+300)$

**Notice: $302/2 = 151$**

$5((2+300)+(3+299)+(4+298)+(5+297)+...(149+153)+(150+152)+(151))$

$5(302+302+302+302+...+302+302+151)$

**There are $(150-2+1)$ 302s, so:**

$5((150-2+1)(302) + 151)$

$5((149)(302) + 151)$

$5(44998 + 151)$

$5(45149)$

---

The answer is $225745$.

Comment: lol thanks and i did a project on C.F. Gauss haha

Comment: @Ronnie Oh really? What's his last name?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 3** (Gauss): $10 + 1500 = 15 + 1495 = 20 + 1490 = \cdots = 1500 + 10$.